# Is Lebesgue measure on $B([3, 5])$ is a probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory

Is Lebesgue measure on $B([3, 5])$ is a probability measure?

$|5-3|=2 \notin [0,1]$ So is it not a probability measure?

Comment: Indeed.${}{}{}$

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Thnx bro.